# What does the "Enable NTLMv2" option mean in a Windows tweaker?

Tags: windows, ntlm

I'm going over some options in a Windows Tweaker and one of them is "enable NTLMv2".

I've looked this up a bit, but the main question I have: how can I benefit from this, and does it work if not enabled on other computers/servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NTLM/v2 has to do with user authentication over a network. The decision on the LMCompatibilityLevel needs to take into account the types of systems used in the environment and how high the threat of attack is. If your O/S is reasonably recent I wouldn't worry about it.

See [NTLMv2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM#NTLMv2) in wikipedia.org.
But even better is this article : [The Most Misunderstood Windows Security Setting of All Time](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.08.securitywatch.aspx).